# reload event file in Crusader Kings2

Tags: crusader-kings-2

While working on event files, I have to restart the game every time I make a change so that the game loads the updated file. Is there a console command to do this without restarting the game?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

The game loads its events on start up once. It doesn't read them on run-time from the disk every time.

From [CK2 official page](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Troubleshooting#Loading):

> When launching the game the following steps occur:
>
> - Initialising Map Logic
> - Loading Databases
> - Generating Coat of Arms
> - **Loading Events**
> - Loading Sounds(Loading of vanilla history files occurs here (even if is replace_path), though it'll still show as "Loading Sounds") - very
>     slow step !
> - Processing Flags - generates the flag sprites in gfx\flags from the individual .tga files
> - Loading Flags
> - Loading Graphics
> - Creating Provinces
> - Loading Map(Creating Terrain)
> - Loading Map(Creating Borders)
> - Loading Map(Creating Trees)
> - Loading Map(Creating Textures)

So once the events have been loaded, Game won't read the file again even if you modify it. It will keep running the cached version which will be the one before your modifications.

The only way to load the updated files into the game is to restart it and thereby reloading all the files.